# ¿Cómo extraer datos de modelo en MongoDB usando findOne?

Tags: nodejs, express, mongoose

Necesito una orientación de cómo puedo extraer los datos de un usuario usando la función de `findOne`.

Estoy realizando una API REST para un proyecto; realizo la conexión a la base de datos, inserto y busco normalmente, pero al momento de llamar a una función dentro del controller la función `findOne` me devuelve todo el objeto pero yo requiero solamente unos datos en específico.

Acá les dejo el código.

```js
exports.getKey = async(req, res) => {

  const {
    username
  } = req.body;

  const userInfo = userModel.findOne({
    username: username
  }, function(err, obj) {

    return {
      first: obj.first_name
    }

  });


  return res.status(200).send({
    data: {
      'status': true,
      'first_name': userInfo

    }
  });

}
```

El código resultante

```
  _id: new ObjectId("61d6fe193ad4693c5d6843a4"),
  first_name: 'test.',
  last_name: 'test.',
  email: 'test@test.com',
  username: 'test',
  password: '$2a$10$oieyVrxCyA0JMmaabpRlCe.tzO4dyWAEcxOzQqY5Vx/dQhoAGQHii',
  token: null,
  status: 'true',
  cypher: 'false',
  __v: 0
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal para que me devuelva todo el objeto y no solo lo que estoy necesitando?

Answer (score 2):

**Si deseas seguir utilizando callback, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:**

```
exports.getKey = async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.body;

  userModel
    .findOne({ username: username }, function (err, obj) {
      return res.status(200).send({
        data: {
          status: true,
          first_name: obj.first_name,
        },
      });
    })
    .select("first_name");
};
```

**Si deases utilizar async y await, puedes hacerlo de esta otra:**

```
exports.getKey = async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.body;

  const userInfo = await userModel.findOne({ username: username }).select("first_name");
  res.status(200).send({
    data: {
      status: true,
      first_name: userInfo.first_name,
    },
  });
};
```

Notas de campo:

1 - Si quitas el `select("first_name")` seguirás viendo en la respuesta solo el **first_name**, la diferencia es que si lo dejas viene de la base solo el **first_name** y el **id**, si lo quitas vendrá todo el objeto completo, aunque muestres solo el **first_name**.

2 - Donde ponemos `{username:username}` se podría reemplazar por `{username}`, JavaScript moderno permite hacer eso si tanto la clave como el valor son iguales.

3 - Considerando que estás utilizando una función `async` podrías tomar el segundo camino con el `await`.

Answer (score 0):

Estas devolviendo el objeto completo. Puedes hacerlo de esta manera para que solo traiga el campo deseado.

```js
async(req, res) => {

  const {
    username
  } = req.body;

  const userInfo = await userModel.findOne({
    username: username
  }).select( 'first_name');


  return res.status(200).send({
    data: {
      'status': true,
      'first_name': userInfo.first_name //Debe ser aquí el return
      'first_name_option_2':userInfo //Te devuelve _id y first_name

    }
  });

}
```